# Group results of same taxonomy term with search api and views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I have couple of products which are classified with taxonomy terms.

I am using Search API with views to display search results.

I want to show the search results in this way.

**Term 1 Name**

- product 1
- product 2
- product 3

**Term 2 Name**

- product 5
- product 8
- product 3

**Term 3 Name**

- product 10
- product 25
- product 1

What should I look into? Any idea how canIi group the results based on the term?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your views, in editing mode , in formatting section, near table, select `settings`,
and then in `Grouping field Nr.1` select your taxonomy field ,save ,it makes the views result goruped by selected field in `Grouping field Nr.1`.